# Counter with a final state machine structure in VHDL. QUARTUS

Tags: vhdl, counter, fsm, quartus

I've produced this VHDL code and testing it with a VWF file seems that it works. But the finite state machine that my code produces (I can see it using the QUARTUS tool "state machine viewer") it seems to be wrong. In this FSM seems that in each state it is possible to reach any one else state.
According to my project goals I need a counter that counts from zero to nine and it changes its value according to the value of two input signals w0 and w1. If w0 and w1 are both zero, the counter attends in its current state, if w0 is 0 and w1 is 1 the counter increases by one, if w0 is 1 and w1 is 0 the counter increases by two, if w0 and w1 are both 1 the counter decrements by one. There are also a clock signal and a reset signal.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY counter IS
    PORT(clk, reset :in std_logic;
                      w :in std_logic_vector(1 DOWNTO 0);
                  cont :out std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0););
END;


ARCHITECTURE arch_counter OF counter IS

TYPE state IS (zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine);
SIGNAL numbCorr, numbFuture :state;

BEGIN



    PROCESS(w, numbCorr)
        BEGIN

            CASE numbCorr IS
                WHEN zero => IF w = "00" THEN numbFuture <= zero; 
                            ELSIF w = "01" THEN numbFuture <= one;  
                            ELSIF w = "10" THEN numbFuture <= two;  
                            ELSIF w = "11" THEN numbFuture <= zero; 
                             END IF;
                             cont <= "0000";
                WHEN one => IF  w = "00" THEN numbFuture <= one;
                             ELSIF w = "01" THEN numbFuture <= two;
                             ELSIF w = "10" THEN numbFuture <= three;
                             ELSIF w = "11" THEN numbFuture <= zero;
                             END IF;
                             cont <= "0001";
                WHEN two => IF   w = "00" THEN numbFuture <= two;
                             ELSIF w = "01" THEN numbFuture <= three;
                             ELSIF w = "10" THEN numbFuture <= four;
                             ELSIF w = "11" THEN numbFuture <= one;
                             END IF;
                             cont <= "0010";
                WHEN three => IF     w = "00" THEN numbFuture <= three;
                             ELSIF w = "01" THEN numbFuture <= four;
                             ELSIF w = "10" THEN numbFuture <= five;
                             ELSIF w = "11" THEN numbFuture <= two;
                             END IF;
                             cont <= "0011";
                WHEN four => IF      w = "00" THEN numbFuture <= four;
                             ELSIF w = "01" THEN numbFuture <= five;
                             ELSIF w = "10" THEN numbFuture <= six;
                             ELSIF w = "11" THEN numbFuture <= three;
                             END IF;
                             cont <= "0100";
                WHEN five => IF w = "00" THEN numbFuture <= five;
                             ELSIF w = "01" THEN numbFuture <= six;
                             ELSIF w = "10" THEN numbFuture <= seven;
                             ELSIF w = "11" THEN numbFuture <= four;
                             END IF;
                             cont <= "0101";
                WHEN six => IF   w = "00" THEN numbFuture <= six;
                             ELSIF w = "01" THEN numbFuture <= seven;
                             ELSIF w = "10" THEN numbFuture <= eight;
                             ELSIF w = "11" THEN numbFuture <= five;
                             END IF;
                             cont <= "0110";
                WHEN seven => IF     w = "00" THEN numbFuture <= seven;
                             ELSIF w = "01" THEN numbFuture <= eight;
                             ELSIF w = "10" THEN numbFuture <= nine;
                             ELSIF w = "11" THEN numbFuture <= six;
                             END IF;
                             cont <= "0111";
                WHEN eight => IF     w = "00" THEN numbFuture <= eight;
                             ELSIF w = "01" THEN numbFuture <= nine;
                             ELSIF w = "10" THEN numbFuture <= nine; 
                             ELSIF w = "11" THEN numbFuture <= eight;
                             END IF;
                             cont <= "1000";
                WHEN nine => IF      w = "00" THEN numbFuture <= nine;
                             ELSIF w = "01" THEN numbFuture <= nine; 
                             ELSIF w = "10" THEN numbFuture <= nine; 
                             ELSIF w = "11" THEN numbFuture <= eight;
                             END IF;
                             cont <= "1001";
                END CASE;


        END PROCESS;

        PROCESS(clk)
            BEGIN 
                IF (rising_edge(clk)) THEN 
                    IF reset = '0' THEN numbCorr <= numbFuture ;
                    ELSE numbCorr <= zero; 
                    END IF;
                END IF;

            END PROCESS;



END;
```

I think with this code is not possible that if the current state is "zero" the future state will be for example "seven" (from the FSM viewer seems that is possible). It is correct or I'm wrong?

this is the FSM produced by quartus (the numberState are in Italian because my original code was in italian to)

[image]

Comment: *The image isn't a state transition diagram lacking condition branches.* The number of lines don't appear to match your code (which isn't a [mcve]). You've asked a yes/no question that doesn't appear to be a programming question. I'd personally venture an *opinion* the diagram describes possible branches. The mux in front of the numbCorr register has all possible state values (examine the logic produced). Your code doesn't analyze (compile) as is, there's an extra separator (semicolon) following the last interface element declaration in the port interface list.

Comment: It's a finite state machine, not a final state machine. Your first process is generating latches for signal `numbFuture`.

Comment: All four binary values of w are represented in each if statement's conditions for each of the state choices in the first process case statement and all have assignment to numbFuture. All evaluated signals are in the process sensitivity list. Input doesn't contain metalogical values for verification. There are no "executions of the process that do not execute an explicit assignment" (IEEE Std 1076.6-2004, RTL Synthesis, *withdrawn*, 5. Verification methodology, 6.2.1.1 Level-sensitive storage from process with sensitivity list - does not meet requirement c)). It won't synthesize latches.

Comment: The behavior you try to achieve can be described way simpler without the need of an FSM. You just need one process for an up/down counter/adder.